# Iron-router and Meteor.user: route called two times

Tags: javascript, meteor, authentication, iron-router

I'm using Iron router's `onBeforeAction` method to check if user is logged on all routes except the register and login routes:

```js
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
        this.render('login');
    }
    else {
        this.next();
    }
}, {except: ['login', 'register']});
```

*(FYI, the login process is made in the login template/js with [this code](http://bulenttastan.net/login-with-facebook-using-meteor-js/))*

This works well, except that when I'm logged the login template shows quickly before being replaced by the actual template.

When I checked what's happening, I found that `Meteor.user()` is not ready before the Iron router is. As a consequence, the login page is showed like the user wasn't logged. And then (as `Meteor.user()` is reactive), the route will run again when `Meteor.user()` becomes ready, showing the correct template.

**How can I make this little sample of code above working correctly?** (Meaning: without showing the login template because of `Meteor.user()` is not ready)

I've also found here on Stack Overflow that I can use the [fast-render package](https://meteorhacks.com/fast-render/), but I'm not willing to hack the render process. The `onRun()` method doesn't fix this problem neither.
I've also read somewhere that I can use `Router.configure`'s `waitOn` option but the only examples I've got are with subscriptions which I don't have yet (I'm prototyping with the insecure auto publish package).

Comment: This won't help much, but I am experiencing the same issues with IR and have heard that flow router doesn't randomly re-render. Basically, I have come to terms with switching to Flow Router.

Comment: @Ruby_Pry Well, that's a drastic approach! But I'm sure there is still hope. Especially somewhere around `waitOn`. Please someone, show us your light! :)

Comment: By the way, I even tried with the official documentation's `this.isReady()` way but it's not working (looks like it's waiting for subscription). @Ruby_Pry : I found a way though. I'll post it here now.

Comment: Not drastic given its the main router used by the meteor community going forward. Also, it has ongoing support, which Iron Router is currently lacking.

Comment: @Ruby_Pry thank you, I didn't know that. I'll give a try for the next project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the best solution, but the trick works fine:

```js
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
   if (Meteor.user() !== undefined) {
        if (!Meteor.user()) {
            this.render('login');
        }
        else {
            this.next();
        }
    }
    else {
        this.pause();
    }
}, {except: ['login', 'register']});
```

This code sample works because `Meteor.user()` is *undefined* before becoming ready and it is *null* if it's ready but there is no user logged in.

For my project, I even replaced `this.pause()` by the loading screen:

```js
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
   if (Meteor.user() !== undefined) {
        if (!Meteor.user()) {
            this.render('login');
        }
        else {
            this.next();
        }
    }
    else {
        this.render('loading');
    }
}, {except: ['login', 'register']});
```

I hope this will help somebody else.